# Running test case for a duration of time in Robot Framework

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

I wanted to run robot test for a duration of time, say for 1hr. No matter if the execution of all test cases in a test suite is completed. It should repeat the test cases until the given time reached.

I tried to use **--prerunmodifier** and tried to write my own module, I used robot.api module **robot.running.context**, and override the present method **end_suite()**. But not successful! :(

Comment: Maybe you can run your RF test cases in Jenkin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with '[Repeat Keyword](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Repeat%20Keyword)' keyword. It takes as argument for how long it should repeat given keyword. But in this case all your test cases should go to one keyword.
Use 'Run Keyword And Ignore Error' inside of it so you ignore errors.

E.g.:

```
Repeat Keyword   2h    Keyword With All Test Cases
```

Second option would be writing a [Listener](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface) - has similar functionality as prerun modifier but is executed during tests not before.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Robot framework user guide the robot framework test suite will be executed for a maximum time of 120 minutes i.e. 2hrs. Not we can overwrite this timeout by explicitly mentioning the test execution time in the test files Settings table as below

```
***Setting***
Test Timeout  60 minutes
```

Further you are most welcome to set a test cases specific timeout using [Timeout] option as below

```
***Test Cases***
Sample Test Case
  [Timeout]  5 minutes
  Do some testing
  Validate some results
```

Feel free to try and ask further questions.

Comment: Isn't the **[Timeout]** setting used to terminate a test when the keyword takes too long to get executed? I guess the question is to run a test case for a certain amount of time. Something like running it in loop for 5 mins.

Comment: @Sameem yes, it is; this seeing is a cut-off point if a case or keyword takes too much time - i.e. for stopping it hanging the execution. It hardly achieves your what you ask for, plus it is per-case setting (or per-keyword), not for the execution. It also is nowhere close to the cycle re-execution of the suites within the expected time (this sentence in the question, "It should repeat the test cases until the given time reached.")

Comment: @TodorMinakov Exactly my thoughts!. But is there a way to re-execute a test case for a certain time in robot irrespective of the test result(either in the command line options or in the test/suite level settings)?